# COVID air restrictions within Mexico?

Tags: covid-19, mexico

If denied boarding for a flight to USA from Jalisco or Sinaloa, what are the current restrictions on a flight from either of those states, or Nayarit, to TIJ for a land crossing?  I know it could change, but knowing today’s rules is better than knowing nothing at all.  I know there are checkpoints on roads in the area to enforce movement restrictions.

I’ll be with an Oregon group returning late April, and some of them don’t speak Spanish.

We’ll be there longer than the three-day test limit, so they’ll have to get tested at their own expense down there.

Comment: I have neither knowledge nor control over their attitudes or their actions.

Comment: Are they all US citizens or permanent residents (or spouses or minor children of US citizens or permanent residents)? Entry via the US land border is still restricted to essential travel for foreigners, whereas entry by air is not. Also note that there is no COVID test requirement for entry to the US by land.

Comment: I don’t yet know who they are, but they’re all either citizens or legal residents.  I doubt they’ll resist the requirements, but I’m aware there are people in this country who would.  Just trying to “be prepared” …

Answer (score 2):

For lack of a better, officially sourced answer, I'll post my second-hand information.

I have friends who have traveled domestically within Mexico over the past few months, and none have been required to get a covid test or show negative test results.  This may, of course, change or be different at different airports.

One couple were pointed towards on-site covid testing at one of the airports, made available for travelers to the US, however as my friends weren't traveling to the US they didn't need to get the test.  This option may suit your traveling group, being able to get tested at the airport for flights to the USA.  This was at Cancun airport - it may also be available at other airports that fly the the US.

Comment: Testing is available in PVR and some hotels in the area offer it for free.  I was just trying to plan ahead in case someone was positive or refused the test.

Comment: @WGroleau Well as I said, AFAIK testing isn't currently required for domestic flights.  That said, if they're positive they should be quarantined, not traveling in a plane full of others (or in the airport or anywhere else).

Comment: That’s true, but they don’t speak Spanish, and I can’t stay there with them.  So I need to think about all other ways to get to the border.  Rent a car maybe.

Comment: None of them refused the test at the airport, and all were negative.  So the question no longer matters to me, but since conditions change, updates and answers might be useful to others.  For what it's worth, if we had more time, we could have gone downtown for the tests and paid one-tenth what we paid at the airport.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, there are less and less restrictions, just like in the USA, the Mexican authorities are vaccinating their population at an impressive rate, [here](https://www.airportcancun.com/covid-19) you can find more updated information about the status of Covid in Cancun, but is the same for all Mexico.